# Setting Font Color in PdfPCell/Paragraph Weirdness

Tags: java, colors, itext, paragraph

I've encountered what I think is a weird problem setting colors. The following code works:

```
Font nameFont=new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 20.f, Font.BOLD,new BaseColor(mon.getColor().getRGB()));
Paragraph name=new Paragraph(mon.getName(),nameFont);
PdfPCell c=new PdfPCell(name);
```

However, this code does not work (it uses the color of the previous cell):

```
Font nameFont=new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 20.f, Font.BOLD,new BaseColor(mon.getColor().getRGB()));
Paragraph name=new Paragraph(mon.getName());
name.setFont(nameFont);
PdfPCell c=new PdfPCell(name);
```

Can someone explain why this happens? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the font of a paragraph does **not** change the font of all text in it, it merely sets the default font to use for further additions to it. Thus, your

```
Paragraph name=new Paragraph(mon.getName());
name.setFont(nameFont);
```

keeps the font of the existing content `mon.getName()`. If you did something like

```
name.add("some additional text");
```

thereafter, you'd see that the additional text was using your font.

`Paragraph` inherits this behaviour from `Phrase`.

Comment: That is a bit confusing but now I understand what it is doing. Thanks.